# Error se agoto el tiempo de ejecucion (en el momento de un insert) VB.net SQL server

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, server

Buen dia , tengo un problema con un codigo y si bien al principio pelie por el uso de begin transaction ahora el tema es que cuando quiero ejecutar el momento del insert queda trabado hasta tirarme erro de tiempo de ejecucion
no se pero esto me pasa en el momento del for, pero otras veces probe sin for y me pasaba cando el query text consultaba su valor

> ` Public Sub Ingresar(ByVal venta As entidadVenta, ByVal item As List(Of entidadVentaItem))
> Dim command As SqlCommand = cn.CreateCommand()

```
    Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO ventas (IDCliente,Fecha,Total)VALUES ('" & venta.IdCliente & "', 
    '" & venta.Fecha & "', '" & venta.Total & "');"

    tran = cn.BeginTransaction("Simple transaccion")
    command.Connection = cn
    command.Transaction = tran

    Try
        command.CommandText = query
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("error " + ex.Message)
        tran.Rollback()
    End Try
    Try
        For Each a As entidadVentaItem In item

            Dim queryItem As String = "INSERT INTO ventasitems (IDVenta,IDProducto,PrecioUnitario,Cantidad,PrecioTotal)VALUES 
            ('" & IDVentaR() & "', '" & a.IdProducto & "', '" & CDbl(a.PrecioUnidad) & "', 
            '" & CDbl(a.Cantidad) & "', '" & CDbl(a.Total) & "');"

            command.CommandText = queryItem
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next

        tran.Commit()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("error " + ex.Message)
        tran.Rollback()
    End Try

End Sub`
```

<
lo que intento es ingresar primero un query que ingrese una venta, de ahi pedir su id para poder registrar items  de un for

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! nunca vi usar dim en c# :p.. de paso.. donde obtenes el id que ingresaste antes para poder ingresarlo en la nueva tabla? supongo que estas dentro de la misma conexion y transaccion...  no?

Comment: Seguramente tienes alguna transacción abierta y está bloqueando cualquier movimiento en esa tabla.

Comment: Opino como Luis Cazares, seguramente existe otra transacción abierta que bloquea que puedas trabajar sobre esa tabla. Revisa la función IDVentaR(), no vaya a ser que estés ahí abriendo una nueva transacción o algo así. O incluso, si en esa función estás haciendo la consulta para el ID, si te estás olvidando de pasar la transacción actual.